# What Limitations Does SubtractSides Have When Applied to an Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't figure this out. [SubtractSides](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubtractSides.html) says

[image]

Then why does this one fail

```
 SubtractSides[x - 2 == (y - 1)/8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But this works

```
 SubtractSides[x - 2 == y/8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What Am I missing?

V 13.1 on windows 10

Comment: @xzczd Ah! ok, sure. But help says `producing a zero right-hand side`. It did not say that user needs to use Simplify to get the zero. It is bit annoying. But may be not a bug then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(1 - y)/8 + 1/8 (-1 + y)` is zero:

```
(1 - y)/8 + 1/8 (-1 + y) // Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

So `SubtractSides` doesn't fail, it just gives an output that looks a bit funny. If I have to guess, it gives this output because:

```
# - # &[(y - 1)/8]
(* (1 - y)/8 + 1/8 (-1 + y) *)
```

Comment: You should `Map` the `Simplify` to get the desired form, i.e., `Simplify /@ SubtractSides[x - 2 == (y - 1)/8]`. It subtracted from both sides, but the result was too complicated for the limited simplification that is done automatically.